limite de duración de input
soy nuevo en la programación y estos días he estado practicando y aprendiendo pygame, la cosa es, que quiero hacer un salto para el personaje, para lo cual quiero limitarlo a que dicho salto pueda durar dos segundo y despues caiga, sin imbargo, he intentado de varias maneras y no funciona, es decir, el personaje sube pero no tiene límite, sigue subiendo mientras mantenga la tecla "w", así que apreciaría algo de ayuda. Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock

#classes

class AllSprites(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, weight, height):
        self.image = image
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
    
    def place(self, x, y):
        self = pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 50)  
class IsPressed():
    def __init__(self, ispressed):
        self.ispressed = ispressed     


#Colors
ColorRed = (255, 0, 0)
ColorBlack = (0, 0, 0)
ColorWhite = (255, 255, 255)
running = True

#objects

player = pygame.Rect(300, 200, 50, 50)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
knight = pygame.image.load("sprites/HollowKnightSprite.webp")
Knight = AllSprites(knight, 50, 50)
KnightRect = Knight.image.get_rect()
Floor = pygame.Rect(0, 650, 1000, 50)

#state variables

CanJump = True
W = IsPressed(False)
AirTime = 0
IsJumping = False
MaxJumpDuration = 2000

#main bucle

while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            raise SystemExit
    screen.fill(ColorBlack) 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ColorWhite, Floor)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ColorBlack, KnightRect)
    screen.blit(knight, KnightRect)

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] and CanJump == True:
        W.ispressed = True
        IsJumping = True
        AirTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] == False:
        W.ispressed = False
        if W.ispressed == False:
            CanJump = False
            IsJumping = False
    if IsJumping == True:
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime < MaxJumpDuration:
            KnightRect.y += -2
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime > MaxJumpDuration:
                IsJumping = False
   
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
        KnightRect.x += 1
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
        KnightRect.x += -1   
    KnightRect.y += 1    
    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(KnightRect, Floor):
        AirTime = 0
        KnightRect.y += -1 
        CanJump = True
    
    pygame.display.flip()


Es un pequeño error de lógica. Deberías poder saltar solo cuando estás en el suelo. Sin embargo, CanJump no se establece en False cuando deja de estar en el suelo.
Puedes solucionarlo agregando 2 líneas:
if pygame.Rect.colliderect(KnightRect, Floor):
    AirTime = 0
    KnightRect.y += -1 
    CanJump = True
else:
    CanJump = False


Aprovecho a mencionar que no hay forma posible de que el segundo if de este bloque de código se llegue a ejecutar. Por qué no usas un else?
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime < MaxJumpDuration:
    KnightRect.y += -2
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime > MaxJumpDuration:
        IsJumping = False

Por cierto, CanJump == True es lo mismo que simplemente CanJump, y CanJump == False es lo mismo que not CanJump.

No estás deteniendo el salto de manera prematura?  Es decir, el salto es un movimiento que comienza en el suelo, luego subes, alcanzas el máximo y bajas nuevamente y terminas en el momento en que realizas el contacto con el suelo.
Al momento de realizar los 2 primeros IF y soltar la W estás deteniendo el salto, incluso si este aún no ha acabado, lo tienes puesto apenas sueltas la tecla W.
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] and CanJump == True:
    W.ispressed = True
    IsJumping = True
    AirTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] == False: # La W se suelta
    W.ispressed = False # Pones la variable en False
    if W.ispressed == False: # If redundante, siempre vas a entrar acá
        CanJump = False # No puede saltar
        IsJumping = False # Detiendes el salto

Entonces, una vez se ha soltado la tecla, no hay forma de que entres al siguiente IF o si ?
# IsJumping = False - el anterior IF lo deja en false, por lo que nunca entramos en esta seccion
if IsJumping == True:
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime < MaxJumpDuration:
        KnightRect.y += -2
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime > MaxJumpDuration:
            IsJumping = False

Peor aún, en cualquier caso ya sea True o False, nunca logras entrar al tercer IF dentro de esta última validación.
Si tu segunda validación es:
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime < MaxJumpDuration:

No hay forma que la siguiente se cumpla o si? Son opuestas una a la otra.
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - AirTime > MaxJumpDuration:

Por lo que el cálculo se realiza de la siguiente forma para ambos... simulando valores claramente. Y pues, es incorrecto en todo sentido.
# IsJumping == True
# pygame.time.get_ticks() = 1100
# AirTime = 1000
# MaxJumpDuration = 200
if True:  
    if 1100 - 1000 < 200: # 100 < 200 = True
        KnightRect.y += -2
        if 1100 - 1000 > 200: # 100 > 200 = False
            IsJumping = False

